# Css change color on parent

Tags: css

Is there a way to change color off a parent when an input gets focus
Check out the demo. I want the div to be red instead of blue when input has focus.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/IpEHUJe/1/edit)

Comment: No there isn't currently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Not without JavaScript.

Comment: You'd think, by now, the smart people writing the specifications would have realized the need to be able to traverse the DOM in both directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a bit of a cheaty way of doing it using CSS only...

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/6fRUd/

### HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
}
div * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
div input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10000px 10000px lime;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: I like this but the `box-shadow` hides any other elements.

Comment: @iambriansreed fixed that issue. See changes :)

Comment: Nice. I'd +1 again if I could. I really don't think I have seen `box-shadow` used like that. Really neat.

Comment: Creative. I wonder how this impacts performance on slower computers. Of course, computers that would probably have a problem with this are probably using a browser that doesn't support `box-shadow` lol

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that in pure CSS, but you can use Javascript:

http://jsbin.com/uvon/1/edit?html,js,output

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var div = document.getElementById('div');

input.onfocus = function(){
  input.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

input.onblur = function(){
  input.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery approach would be using .parent()

```
<script>$("p").parent(".selected").css("background", "yellow");</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 1):

CSS **Only** Approach

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/GT5sT/

**CSS**

```
input {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
input:focus,
input:focus + div { background-color: red }
div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
div.background-hack {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input />
    <div class="background-hack"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated fiddle with a few minor changes for your perusal: http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/GT5sT/1/

Comment: Nice. I was going to go there until I saw your answer. Less html the better which is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use javascript.

Here is a short script using jquery.

```
$('#input').focus(function(){
  $('#box').css('background-color','red');
});
```

This is assuming your input has an id of `input` and blue box has an id of `box`.

Comment: Wouldn't using `.parent()` be better? `$('input').focus(function(){ $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red'); });`

Comment: Yeah it would he if they are going to have multiple instances of this on the page.

Answer (score 0):

javascript also works here look at the code below,it is more flexible than just using css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById('box').style.background="red";

    }
  </script>  
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box" style="background-color:blue">
    <input onfocus="myFunction()" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```